# Android application

Tags: android

Whenever i login to application i need to enter the password.But next time when i enter the password it shows me complete password over the soft keyboard of android.I need to clear this
data from android memory.

Comment: This is vague. Is this an app you wrote? Provide some code showing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the password hint to be shown try adding the following to your EditText attributes

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: Thanks for ur comments but this does not work as it is using json instead of Xml.So is there any other way.

Comment: @Rinks05 You can set the inputType from code: editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS); etc. I don't know anything about json, sorry